# Add extra field to each Sitecore Forms element

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need to extend every form element of Sitecore Forms with a `Tooltip` field. Obviously I'll have to extend all Razor views, but I'm looking for a way of adding a field to the base form element template and mapping this value to the View Model.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to override the code of each and every form element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

But, a lot of the form elements use the same model class. (A lot of them are StringInputViewModels).

It's a good practice to provide an interface containing your new properties and creating new classes extending from the original version + implementing your interface.

For the repeatable code in those classes to init the binding settings and update the binding settings you can create an extension class.

**Example:**

```
public interface IBindingSettings
{
    ValueProviderSettings ValueProviderSettings { get; set; }
    bool StoreBindingValue { get; set; }
}

public static class BindingSettingsItemMapperExtension
{
    private const string StoreBindingValueParam = "Store Binding Value";

    public static void InitBindingSettingsProperties(this IBindingSettings bindingSettings, Item item)
    {
        bindingSettings.StoreBindingValue = MainUtil.GetBool(item.Fields[StoreBindingValueParam]?.Value, false);
    }

    public static void UpdateBindingSettingsFields(this IBindingSettings bindingSettings, Item item)
    {
        item.Fields[StoreBindingValueParam]?.SetValue(bindingSettings.StoreBindingValue ? "1" : string.Empty, true);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class StringInputViewWithBindingsTokenModel : StringInputViewModel, IBindingSettings
{
    public bool StoreBindingValue { get; set; }

    protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
    {
        base.InitItemProperties(item);
        this.InitBindingSettingsProperties(item);
    }

    protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
    {
        base.UpdateItemFields(item);
        this.UpdateBindingSettingsFields(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still is looking for an answer what is needed to add extra field like tooltip to each Sitecore Forms field, here is the list:

- `Tooltip` folder and `Tooltip text` item under `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Common` item in `core` database, similar to e.g. `Label` item
- `TooltipExpander` item (duplicate of `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Common/Sections/DetailsExpander`),
- `Tooltip` section item in `core` database - duplicate of `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/PropertyGridForm/PageSettings/Settings/SingleLineText/Details` with 2 items above selected in the ConfigurationItem and ControlDefinitions fields (and for any other field that should have tooltip)
- new view model class inheriting from `StringInputViewModel` with `TooltipText` property (and for any other field that should have tooltip):

  ```
   public string TooltipText { get; set; }

   protected override void InitItemProperties(Item item)
   {
       base.InitItemProperties(item);
       TooltipText = StringUtil.GetString(item.Fields["Tooltip Text"]);
   }

   protected override void UpdateItemFields(Item item)
   {
       base.UpdateItemFields(item);
       item.Fields["Tooltip Text"]?.SetValue(TooltipText, false);
   }
  ```
- change to your `Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\SingleLineText.cshtml` - depending on how you want tooltips to be rendered  (and for any other field that should have tooltip),
- `Tooltip text` field on `/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Fields/Field`
- `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Basic/Single-Line Text` must referece your new view model class   (and for any other field that should have tooltip).

Source of the answer: https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-add-tooltips-to-forms-fields